Problema en WebSocket usado en WebView de Android TV
Tengo una aplicacion que corre en un televisor Android TV y que tambien la tengo instalada en mi celular, dicha aplicacion es sencilla, solo muestra con un web view una determinada pagina web, dicha pagina web tiene una conexion web socket, y cuando le llega un mensaje por dicha conexion, muestra un div que contiene el mensaje que llego por el socket al usuario, el problema es que funciona bien si se abre la pagina web en un nevegador web, tambien si se abre usando la app del celular, pero en el televisor android tv, falla de ves en cuando, y con "falla" me refiero a que no hace nada, no muestra el mensaje que le llego por el socket, no muestra nada, ni el div, simplemente no hace nada.
Seria de gran ayuda que me dieran ideas de como depurar eso, gracias de antemano.
(el socket esta en un servidor de node, y use codigo nativo tanto en el server como en el cliente, es decir, no use librerias)
